# Position of my <li> circles is different between IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

This is a follow-up to my last question. Thanks to "mu is too short" I can now demonstrate my problem in a fiddle.

I have the following code.

I want the code to show the list circles to the left of the text but to the right side of the .img DIV. This works in Firefox and in Opera but in IE they are positioned to the very far left. I can't understand why they are positioned differently in the two browsers. Help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="fp1">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="img" id="img1"></div>
                        <ul>
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>        
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>
                        </ul>
      </div>
</div>

.fp1 .row   { overflow: hidden;  }
.fp1 .img   { display: inline-block; float: left; width:105px; height:80px; margin:25px 0 10px 0;
    background: yellow; no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }

.fp1 .col   { float: left; width:50%; margin:0px; }
.fp1 .col ul      { margin:15px 20px 0 0; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 1.2em}
.fp1 .col ul span { color:#222; font-size: 0.85em; }
.fp1 .col ul li   { line-height:15px; }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fdxtq/)

Comment: This fiddle looks exactly the same to me in FF4 and IE8. If you're troubleshooting IE, please specify version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My CSS isn't great, but I think you need something like this:

```
.fp1 .col ul      { display: inline-block; float: left; margin:15px 20px 0 0; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 1.2em}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Fdxtq/2/)

I did a couple of things based on my experience. Most importantly:

1. I have floated the `UL` towards left
2. I have zeroed out all margin/padding on the `UL` (except padding left so that the bullet stays there)
3. I have zeroed out all margin/padding on the `LI`

Note that different browsers have different defaults for margin/padding on `UL` and `LI` hence the normalization.

## [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Fdxtq/3/)

This is almost the same as above except `UL` is not floated, instead a left-margin is used.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why IE does nonsense like this, save for saying IE does this kind of thing  all the time!

The solution is condintional comments.

These allow you to point different css at IE versions only: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

so

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Would target all IE versions, just as

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Would target IE6 only .

so this should fix your problem

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style><!-- 
    .fp1 .row           { overflow: hidden;  }
    .fp1 .img           { display: inline-block; float: left; width:105px; height:80px; margin:25px 0 10px 0; background: yellow; no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }
    .fp1 .col           { float: left; width:50%; margin:0px; }
    .fp1 .col ul      { margin:15px 20px 0 0; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 1.2em}
    .fp1 .col ul span { color:#222; font-size: 0.85em; }
    .fp1 .col ul li   { line-height:15px; }
    --></style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style><!-- 

ul li {
    margin-left: 80px;
    color: red;
}

--></style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="fp1">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="img" id="img1"></div>
                        <ul>
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>        
                        <li><span>Test </span></li>
                        </ul>
      </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE were you seeing an issue in? OP's fiddle looked fine for me in IE8.

Comment: IE9, but stupid phil's css fix works great and is a more elegant fix than mine!

Comment: I have not used IE9 yet, it's sad to see we're still having IE issues in 2011.

Comment: Couldn't agree more - IE is a pain in the but and the more versions there are the bigger the problem!